# socketio expressjs video chat app not working while connected to different nerworks

Tags: socket.io, videochat

I have a socketio node expressjs video chatting app which works fine when 2 devices video chat on it while connected to the same wifi. I have deployed it on AWS. But when 2 devices try to video chat over the internet, when not connected to the same wifi. It just won't work video won't show up, no error in the console either.
I don't have a valid SSL certificate on it, so it says the website isn't secure, but I have installed a fake SSL cert just to get HTTPS. My question is If I get a real SSL certificate and install it on my AWS ec2 instance will my app start to work over the internet?

Comment: Use letsencrypt to get SSL certificate and check whether it works or not.

Comment: I have used ssl using letsencrypt and the connection is secured. but video/audio is still not showing up